# MOSFET problem when connecting load

Tags: mosfet

I have a [MOSFET IRF Z44n](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irfz44n.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153563b3575220b) and want to control 5V using 3.3V at the gate:

If I replace L1 with a voltmeter, the circuit behaves as expected: if SW1 is closed, I measure 5V. If SW1 is open, I measure 0V. I also can connect a lamp in place of L1, and it switches on when SW1 is closed (the lamp pulls less than 10mA).

Now the problem: if I close SW1 and connect the coil L1 that pulls normally about 500mA, I measure 0V in parallel to L1 with a total current of <10mA. Normally, the coil should pull its 500mA and generate a significant magnetic field (which it doesn't). As described above, connecting a lamp works.

Is the problem that the coil is pulling to much current? It isn't above the max current described in the data sheet.
I really don't know what to do.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fD9L26.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Have a look at Fig.3 on pg.3 of the datasheet. You'll notice that they don't even bother to extend the graph below Vgs 4.5V - you're only giving it 3.3V... The specs table on pg.2 lists VGS(th) as 2V(min) to 4V(max), so there's really not any guarantee that the MOSFET will even begin to turn on with 3.3V.

Comment: @brhans I thought V_GS is the difference in voltage between Gate and Source. The source is GND and Gate is at 3.3V - which is between 2V and 4V. What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: The 2-4V Vgs(th) spec says that for less than 2V it's guaranteed to be off and for greater than 4V it's guaranteed to just barely start turning on - that's the threshold. Anything in between is unpredictable. If you want it to turn on 'properly' don't even think of Vgs any less than 5V.

Comment: There are other issues also. You need to add a pull down resistor to the gate so that the gate can discharge when the switch is opened. This is probably just a notation issue, but your voltage source (V2) has the load and FET connected to the "wrong" pole.

Comment: notation issues due to simplification but thx

Comment: @pgvoorhees which pull down resistor would you recommend for this setting? 1MOhm?

Comment: Do you need more than 250uA? Then you'd better supply  more voltage than the max threshold voltage of 4V:

VGS(th) Gate Threshold Voltage 2.0 – 4.0 V VDS = VGS, ID = 250µA

Your meter is a high impedance load which probably doesn't draw more than Id(threshold) so it shows the circuit "working".

Comment: @black 10k would be fine. But any middle-value resistor (10's of k) would be alright. It's not a critically valued component (unless it is, but you'd know).

Comment: Just replace it with an IRLZ44N FTW

Comment: Your schematic is incorrect. Show how V2 is connected.

Answer (score 2):

MOSFET is limiting current, not the coil, so it won't 'pull' more current than the MOSFET is allowing to flow.

Agree with others that you have not fully turned it on @ 3.3V.  Other transistors of the same type MAY turn on fully at 3.3V, but this one does not.

Answer (score 0):

Power Mosfets of this type are usually available in two flavors:

Vgs-th @ 25C between 2 and 4 V and Rdson specified at Vgs=10V
Vgs-th @ 25C between 1 and 2/2.5 V and Rdson specified at Vgs=5V

The suggested gate voltage for good Rdson performance is 10V for the first and 5V for the second.
Your chosen device belongs to the first flavor (also called standard gate). At 3.3 V is basically off, and it will start to show decent performance around ~ 7 V.

You should use a Mosfet of the second flavor (called logic level) and use the 3.3V to drive a bipolar to connect your 5V supply to the Mosfet gate.